# Modal error....send id for right modal view .HOW DO?

Tags: javascript, html, css, simplemodal

I have this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
<title> EURO CATALOGO </title>

<style>
#myImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {    
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)} 
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)} 
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
h1
{
 text-align:center;
}

h2
{
 text-align:center;
 font-size:20px;
}
table, th, td 
{
 border-collapse:collapse;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
th
{
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1><img src="http://www.megghy.com/gif_animate/cose_oggetti/euro/24.gif"></img> EURO CATALOGO <img src="http://www.megghy.com/gif_animate/cose_oggetti/euro/24.gif"></img> <h1>
<h2> di STEFANO LIMONE <h2>


<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">×</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>2004</th><th>2005</th><th>2006</th><th>2006</th><th>2007</th><th>2008</th><th>2009</th><th>2009 UEM</th><th>2010</th><th>2011</th><th>2012</th><th>2012 TYE</th><th>2012</th><th>2013</th><th>2014</th><th>2014</th><th>2015</th><th>2015</th><th>2015 flag</th> <th> 2016 </th>
  <tr>
    <td>ANDORRA</td>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><img id="myImg" src="ANDORRA/2euro2014.jpg" alt="20° anniv. ingresso Andorra nel Consiglio europeo"
  width="300" height="200"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script>
// Get the modal

var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');


 // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    modalImg.alt = this.alt;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
  modal.style.display = "none";
}


</script>
```

I want to send not the same id at line 148 :

```
var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
```

how do I send a different id? i'm trying to make an `onClick` function that sends "this.id" in a img and this.id saved in a var=id...  but is not read in the 148 line instruction. Why?

Please can you help me?

The modal instruction work for a single image with the same id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
function openModel(imgId) {
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');


    // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById(imgId);
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    modalImg.alt = this.alt;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
}
```

Comment: thnks mate but now work on a second click the first time ....why?:/ thanks for patients

Comment: You should use jQuery to bind correctly click events on button and img. Each time you'll call "openModal" you bind click event on the given image: that's  not really good. Or better: use jQueryUI Dialog with modal settings on https://jqueryui.com/dialog/